# Reactjs MUI - useState

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multiple-select

I am new to ReactjS, here I try to create a multiple select

```
export const MuiMultiSelect = () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = **useState<string[]>([])**;
    console.log({countries})
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value
        setCountries(typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value);
      }
    ...
```

Got the following error :

> "Parsing error: Missing semicolon." for the highlighted line

Not sure where the missing semicolon should go. Appreciate any pointers.

I have tried using the statement from the official documentation, but still no luck

Comment: Your last semicolon is for the function handleChange. Have you added semicolon for the MuiMultiSelect ?

Comment: I'd search in the code above this snippet.

Comment: Tangential, but pick a semicolon convention and stick with it (with the caveat that opting to not use semicolons can lead to very annoying errors that are difficult to track down).

Comment: @MarioVernari Not much code there other than the imports import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Box, TextField, MenuItem} from '@mui/material';

Comment: If this is your complete function, then aren't you missing `}` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try ending these lines with a semicolon (const and console lines).

```
export const MuiMultiSelect = () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = **useState<string[]>([])**;
    console.log({countries})
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value
        setCountries(typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value);
      }
```

Comment: there is already a semicolon as can be seen in the code snippet

Comment: I see. There are many lines missing a semicolon. Let me know if this helps.